# Maven parent hierarchy + dependencyManagement not transitive?

Tags: java, maven

I thought dependencyManagement from parents were transitive aren't they?
Never see that explicitely in the doc, but it seemed obvious to me...

Here's what i have:

```
+-----------------------+
| Parent 1              |
|-----------------------|
| dependencyManagement: |
|   lib1: 1.0.0         |
+-----------------------+
            ^
            |
            |
+-----------+-----------+
| Parent 2              |
|-----------------------|
| dependencyManagement: |
|   lib2: 1.0.0         |
+-----------------------+
            ^
            |
+-----------+-----------+
| Project A             |
|-----------------------|
| dependencies:         |
|   lib1                |
|   lib2                |
+-----------------------+
```

When i try to mvn install Project A, i get:

```
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for lib1-digester:jar is missing. @ line XX, column YY
```

I also tried to add an entry of **Parent 1** in the dependencyManagement of **Parent 2** with the **import** scope, with no success..

How can my **Project A** have versions managed by all it's parent hierarchy?

Comment: Can you show the real pom files instead something else...

Comment: They're pretty big, and business related... I'll make other poms to illustrate the problem i'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A made a small example with other empty projects, and everything went fine...
Finally, there was something strange, here's what happened.
I was actually more like that:

```
+-----------------------+
| Parent 1              |
|-----------------------|
| dependencyManagement: |<----------------------+
|   lib1: 1.0.0         |                       |
+-----------------------+                       |
            ^                                   |
            |                     +-------------+------------+
            |                     | Project B                |
+-----------+-----------+         |--------------------------|
| Parent 2              |         | dependencies:            |
|-----------------------|         |   somethingWrong: 1.0.0  |
| dependencyManagement: |         +--------------------------+
|   lib2: 1.0.0         |
+-----------------------+
            ^
            |
+-----------+-----------+
| Project A             |
|-----------------------|
| dependencies:         |
|   lib1                |
|   lib2                |
+-----------------------+
```

There was an error in **Project B**'s pom.xml
It shouldn't have any impact on my problem, but correcting that *unrelated* pom solved my problem...

Sorry for the wasted time

Comment: How did you draw the ASCII boxes?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are correct after reading the [Maven Docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

> In general, all dependencies of those projects are used in your project, as are any that the project inherits from its parents, or from its dependencies, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try to update to the latest version of Maven 3. IIRC, there were a couple of bugs in the inheritance of `dependencyManagement` elements.